# Failed to get convolution algorithm while implementing SRCNN

Tags: keras

`UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm.`

This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so I tried looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

```
[[node conv2d_1/convolution (defined at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_899]
```

Function call stack:
`keras_scratch_graph`

Comment: Do you know if you have other processes (maybe other notebooks) with tensorflow/keras running?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi i do not have any other file or process running. The same model is working with PyTorch but it is not working with TF or Keras

Comment: what is the output of `import tensorflow as tf` in a python console?
what is the output of `nvidia-smi` in the terminal?
Usually this message is due to either not enough space on the GPU or incorrect links with cuda machinery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the error, the issue was with the GPU on my laptop. I had GTX 1650 which as causing the error with tensorflow.

There were 2 possible solutions

- use TF CPU instead is TF GPU
- Use Pytorch, it was seem to work fine with me. I was able to get pass the error and use the same GPU 'GTX 1650'